# VS.NET Setting different application icons for different configuration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Although I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612363/how-do-i-set-different-application-icon-for-different-configurations) but the link in accepted answer seems dead, and also this question is about VS 2008.

I am using VS2015, (and VB) and I have the same scenario. The configuration dropdown is still disabled. How do I set different application icon for different configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pre-build step, or you can manually edit the project file in notepad to achieve the goal as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223549/want-different-icons-with-different-builds-in-c-sharp) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003414/in-visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-application-icon-based-on-the-buil).

Comment: It is strange why those threads didn't appear in my search results!!